# std::string concatenation operations

Tags: c++, stl, stdstring

Actually I wondered what different between `std::string` `operator+=` and `append` methods. In first glance they solve the same problem.

In my case resulted string was compiled from different strings, and which of these functions more effective or appropriate? Or should I use `std::stringstream` instead?

How I see, `std::string` has a lot in common with `std::vector` (`capacity`, `reserve` and other methods) and can be reallocated during the appending operation.

Comment: Have you compared https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D with each other?

Comment: Besides the number of overload of each differs, there's really no practical difference from the C++ standard point of view. It might even be possible that some implementations use `append` in their implementation of `+=`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, yes, I had compared them on cplusplus.com, but found out only that the append methods has more overloads e.g. for iterators range. How I see `std::append` included all `operator+=` functionality

Comment: @MalovVladimir Well, given a name like `append`, you would expect it to append characters, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [the standard](https://wg21.link/string.op.append) says:

> `constexpr basic_string& operator+=(const basic_string& str);`
>
> *Effects:* Equivalent to: `return append(str);`

So I would say that they accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Yep, I see. But in which case we should prefer `std::stringstream` to simple string concatenations?

Comment: @MalovVladimir For *simple* concatenations? Probably never. If you want formatted strings or use objects for which there are no overloaded `to_string` function but an overloaded `operator<<`, then `std::ostringstream` is very useful.